# Vertical Tab menu on mobile for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

am trying to achieve the same results as this page . using wordpress elementor.
the page should be only visibile for the mobile version.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello , it's based on Elementor , so technically there is no code , am just trying to reproduce the same aspect